# How to prevent jmeter request from following a redirect

Tags: groovy, jmeter, httpclient

There are two options under HTTP Request- **Redirect Automatically** and **Follow Redirects**. I want to implement behavior when **Follow Redirects** in unchecked

```
//CASE 1: HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
//CASE 2: HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("${request_link}");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
SampleResult.setResponseData(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()));
```

I am using "disableRedirectHandling" as shown above in CASE 2 to stop auto re-direct. But I am getting a 200 response code instead of the expected 302.

This is response I get for CASE 1:
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
Response headers:

But I am expecting below reponse:
Response code: 302
Response message: Found

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 11 Jun 2021 00:32:45 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Location: {redirect location link}

Note:  disableRedirectHandling() is disabling **Redirect Automatically** but what I want to implement is **Disable Follow Redirects**

Basically I want something of this
setRedirectsEnabled(false)
OR setMaxRedirects(0)

I tried this but no luck, Still getting re-direct

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setRedirectsEnabled(true).setMaxRedirects(0).build()).build();
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue against this endpoint  https://httpbin.org/#/Redirects/get_redirect_to  If yes - show full code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CASE 2 looks valid, can it be the case the problem is with your `request_link` variable?

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:

> Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
>
> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
> **When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So try replacing your `HttpGet("${request_link}");` with `HttpGet(vars.get("request_link"));` where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance (see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this and other JMeter API shortcuts)

---

In general, any specific reason for not using JMeter's [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for building the request? It has support of cookie, header, cache manager, embedded resources, authentication, better integration with reporting and so on.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri, first of all, I must say you are a HERO. I tried your suggestion but getting the same result as that of mine. Actually, in both cases, the GET request formation is fine and as expected.  Reason for not using HTTP Request: In my case, I am extracting the entire URL i.e. https://{Host}/{PATH}.html?{Query Parameters} in a variable and I don't want to split  different parts like HOST, PORT, PATH ext and populate HTTP REquest fields. But I will do that now :) . Again it is pleasure to see a response from you Sir!

Comment: You can put the whole URL into "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler